# slice through Text

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, vertices

I'm using Blender 2.8.2a

1. I create the TEXT
2. Object, Convert To, Mesh from Curve/Meta/Text
3. Edit mode (Tab)
4. knife tool
5. press enter key (not right click)
6. Select, Selected Inner Region
7. press P, select

The knife tool kinda works, but  want to dissect letters and I'm struggling to do so. I can Dissect Suzanne - no problem, but not TEXT converted to mesh.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: what is your final task? (note that the topology of the texts is really bad)

Comment: Yup, show us the problem. You may need to clean up the mesh after conversion.